# What is the difference between DTOs and API Resources

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am going through some ASP.NET Core tutorials and articles on how to make a RESTful API. To me, it seems that in newer demos/articles, people refer to DTOs as API Resources. Are these two the very same concept with different names or there is a difference between the two? Is there a standard/convention to follow or is it just opinion based?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a REST or Web API, the resource is the object that the methods are operating upon. For example, get a list of Contact, get a specific Contact by ID, update a Contact, delete a Contact - the Contact is the resource.

A DTO (Data Transfer Object) is one way of implementing such a resource. It is often used when the API is modifying data in a relational database. People have discovered pitfalls with returning a Contact database entity directly to a client over a Web API. So they map the Contact Entity to a Contact DTO.

So a Web API Resource might be a DTO but it doesn't have to be. That would depend on your situation. Imagine you have a Web API to get/set the time of day on a device. You wouldn't need to create a DTO for this, you could just use a string representing the date. In that case, the Resource of the API would be a string.

Comment: Correct but I think that the question was about whether creating special client facing classes/objects suffixed with 'Resource', and which have a different shape from the domain model, are the same as DTOs. I do believe the answer is yes.

Comment: Well they can be the same thing but they do not have to be.  Imagine you have a Readonly service that returns how long you system has been us a long representing seconds since 1999. The long is a resource but it is not a DTO.

Comment: The DTO definition is wrong. DTO has nothing to do with the database. And DTO is not a Resource.

Answer (score 1):

> Are these two the very same concept with different names or there is a difference between the two?

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Identifying_resources_on_the_Web), the resource is the target of an HTTP request. It means that in a PUT request, it is the Request Body. In a GET request, the Response Body.

[DTO](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) is an aggregator data structure that has the purpose to reduce the number of remote calls (can be in a Web API context or not).

> Is there a standard/convention to follow or is it just opinion based?

What I have seen in different companies that I've worked is that people mix up these concepts and tend to suffix all IO classes with `Dto` or `Resource`, which, IMO, is a bad practice. Try to understand the intent of each concept and apply them properly, just remember that for that you don't need to suffix your classes.

Answer (score 0):

They are different concepts but kind of similar

DTOs are objects that are suitable for passing to and from views / clients.  The purpose is to remove information that you don't want, flatten object structures into are more consumable form, or decorate your data with various other things.  They sit between your data model and whatever you want to give your data to.

REST is a highly convention based way to give an API to your data for CRUD type operations.  It's possible Your REST API may use a DTO quite different from the raw data model, though often in tutorials the API is a thin layer over the DB with authentication / authorization checks.

Comment: REST is not about CRUD operations.  REST is about providing a resource-oriented interface to a service. It's quite possible and trivial to implement non-CRUD operations with REST, such as launching background processing tasks.

Answer (score 0):

IF I understand you correctly, I  think that the question is whether having special client facing classes/objects suffixed with 'Resource' (eg, `EmployeeResource`), and which have a different "shape" from the domain model (in  this case, `Employee`), is the same as having DTOs. 
I do believe the answer is yes.